# Oracle Forms - How to open a URL in Chrome

Tags: oracle11g, oracleforms

Is there a way to open a URL within forms, in another browser other than explorer?

Currently running `web.show_document(url, '_blank');' only opens it in explorer`.

For a reason I am unable to use the `host` command, example: `host('cmd /c start chrome "'||url||'"')`. It either does not work or creates an infinite loop within itself, which locks up the file under the system process, causing me to have to restart the IAS/Local machine to unlock it.

The reason I can not use explorer since I'm trying to open a redirecting url with a token, which opens up an angular-based application.

Answer (score 1):

We've been running Forms in MS Internet Explorer ver. 8; an *ancient* one, yes - but - it supported Forms.

As of Chrome, you might be out of luck because Chrome won't support Java applets. It has to do something with support of NPAPI plug-ins which were first disabled and now not even supported. Java applet (Forms, right?) is such a plug-in.

What you might try to do is to enable NPAPI support in Chrome, but only if you (and your users) have a really old Chrome version lower than **45**. Current version is **96**, so we're talking about version that was out back in 2015 or 2016. Can you get such an old version? If so, you'd put `chrome://flags/#enable-npapi` into the address bar, find & enable NPAPI, restart Chrome and - hopefully - make your Forms application work in Chrome.

Otherwise, I'm not sure you can make it work.

Comment: Perhaps any other browsers that do support NPAPI?

Comment: I wouldn't know, sorry.

Comment: I just wanted to report back some findings, since they might be helpful to you or to the next person. Launching the forms application in the `Pale Moon` browser or launching it as a `JNLP` (it will make use of the default browser setting on your pc)

Comment: Huh, Pale Moon browser? Never heard :) Thank you for letting us know!

Comment: Forgot to add: Why Pale Moon? It allows the use of NPAPI as well as it keeps up to date with modern technology. Therefore, in my case where I needed to open up an angular application, it came in handy.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the clientBrowser applet parameter to explicitly indicate which browser you want to use.  The downside to using this is that you must hard code the path to the browser exe, so every user would need to be configured the same way.

clientBrowser=c:\directory\google\chrome.exe

Answer (score -1):

I don't have Oracle Forms now to test properly on, so no code example here, sorry.

You can use the "HOST" in order to execute OS commands. Just like you do it in terminal/cmd

So, try to say the following to open a link in chrome from an Oracle Forms

```
host('chrome.exe www.your.url');
```

It sould be working fine assuming all users have the chrome installed

Comment: If you read my example, I pointed out exactly that it's refusing to do that.

Comment: Hmm, you're right. Strange how I  missed that, sorry